# Maximum horizontal distance of a freefalling ball with one allowed bounce anywhere along its initial path?

Tags: acceleration, collision, free-fall, optimization

I was washing a spoon in the sink and this question popped into my mind:

If a ball is dropped from height H and is allowed a single deflection of any angle $0 < \theta < 180$ at any height $ 0 \leq H' \leq H$, what is the furthest the ball can land from where it would have landed without deflection?  What are the values of $\theta$ and H'?

Assume the following:  2d world, perfect deflection, zero drag, gravity is G, the ball is a point particle.

Comment: Does deflection mean the speed remains the same but the direction changes?

Comment: @Puk: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the equation for the trajectory of a projectile launched from the origin with speed $u$ at angle $\theta$ to the horizontal, with $\tan\theta=m$ :
$$y=mx-\frac{g}{2u^2}(1+m^2)x^2$$

The deflection point is the origin, at height $h$ above ground. Launch speed is given by $u^2=2g(H-h)$. The projectile hits the ground where $y=-h$.

Let $\frac{u^2}{g}=2(H-h)=a$ and $mx=z$. Substitute into the above equation and rearrange :
$$0=2ah+2az-(x^2+z^2)=(2ah-x^2)+2az-z^2$$
Looking at this as a quadratic in $z=xm$, the range $x$ is a maximum when the two possible values of $z$ are the same, ie when the quadratic is a perfect square. This occurs when $2ah-x^2=-a^2$ giving $z=a$.

The optimum range is given by
$$x^2=a^2+2ah=4(H-h)^2+4(H-h)h=4H(H-h)$$

If $H\ge h \ge 0$ then the maximum range is $x=2H$ when $h=0$. If $h$ can take values below $0$ - ie the deflection point is below ground level - then $x$ can be arbitrarily large.

The optimum angle $\theta$ for a particular value of $h$ can be found from $z=mx=a$ :
$$m=\tan\theta=\frac{a}{x}=\sqrt{\frac{H-h}{H}}$$
*Check :* When $h=0$ then $\theta=45^{\circ}$. When $h=H$ then $\theta=0^{\circ}$.

The normal to the deflecting plane should make an angle $\frac12(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)$ with the vertical.

---

Another solution starts with a theorem in Mathematics SE question
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2660468/projectile-vw-gk-for-minimum-launch-velocity/2687554#2687554.

The minimum launch speed $u$ required to reach a point with horizontal separation $x$ is related to the landing speed $v$ by $$uv=gx$$

Maximum deflection for a given launch speed is equivalent to minimum launch speed to reach a given deflection.

Here $u^2=2g(H-h)$ and $v^2=2gH$ therefore
$$x^2=\frac{u^2v^2}{g^2}=\frac{2g(H-h).2gH}{g^2}=4H(H-h)$$
as found above.

Comment: Looks good to me, and matches my results as well.  Although this doesn't include computing theta, I found an equation for that elsewhere.

Comment: @JS_Riddler Answer updated to include calculation of $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's set up some variables. By conservation of energy, at height $H'$, the speed is $$v={\sqrt{2g(H-H')}}. \tag{1}$$

The horizontal distance you want to minimize is $$x= v \cos(\theta)t. \tag{2}$$

Next, after deflection, the time it takes to fall is in the following expression:

$$ -H' = -\dfrac{1}{2}gt^2+v\sin(\theta)t \quad\implies\quad H'=\dfrac{1}{2}gt^2-v\sin(\theta)t \tag{3}$$

We combine equations (2) and (3) and get:
$$H'=\dfrac{1}{2}g\dfrac{x^2}{v^2\cos^2\theta} - v\sin(\theta)\dfrac{x}{v\cos\theta}$$
$$H'=\dfrac{gx^2}{2v^2\cos^2\theta} - x\tan(\theta)$$

Then, we combine (3) and finally get:

$$H'=\dfrac{gx^2}{2{\sqrt{2g(H-H')}}^2\cos^2\theta} - x\tan(\theta)$$
$$H'=\dfrac{x^2}{4(H-H')\cos^2\theta} - x\tan(\theta)$$
$$H'\cos^2(\theta)=\dfrac{x^2}{4H-4H'} - \dfrac{1}{2}x\sin(2\theta) \tag{4}$$

Keep in mind that domain for $x$ is $0\leq H' \leq H$ and $0\leq \theta \leq \pi / 2$.

Since $\theta$ and $H'$ are independent of each other, we'd use partial derivatives. First, we'd take partial derivative wrt $\theta$ of the equation in (4), and then set $\partial x / \partial \theta = 0$. That will give us one equation. Then we'd take partial derivative of equation (4) again, only this time wrt $H'$, and set $\partial x / \partial H' = 0$. That will give us second equation. Then solve that system of equations for $h'$ and $\theta$. Interesting problem!

However, since eq (4) is pretty complicated, its partial derivatives will be even more complicated. I would suggest using a software like Maple or Wolfram Alpha to come up with the real solution.

EDIT: made a mistake. fixing it.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but partial derivatives are beyond me, and I don't see an answer here.  I did the best I could in my own answer, it would be great if you could double check it.

Comment: Later today I will run these equations through a program called Maple which will give me the answers. I will update my post and put them here.

Comment: Sounds good. I'm interested in seeing if we arrive at the same conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

[This document](https://www.usna.edu/Users/physics/mungan/_files/documents/Scholarship/Projectile.pdf) gives an equation for finding the maximum range $R$ of a simple projectile given an initial height from the ground $h$ and velocity $v$:

R = sqrt((2v^2)/g * (h + v^2/(2g)))))

From conservation of energy, we know the velocity $v$ for $H$ and $h$:

v = sqrt(2 * H' * g).

The bigger H', the higher its velocity $v$.

Substituting $v$ into the first equation quite nicely simplifies into:

R = 2 * sqrt(H * H')

For any given $H$ and $H'$, we can now know the optimal range possible.

This appears to be maximal where $H'$ = H. That is, it's best to let the ball fall all the way down.

The document also provides an equation to compute theta given the $h$ and $v$, which we can now produce.  However, it is trivial to see that when $h$ = 0, the optimal angle is 45 degrees.

Note: I'm new here and don't know how to make my equations look nice. I could not find a simple cut and paste thing that will convert simple equations into whatever ridiculous gibberish formats you mathematicians seem content with using :P

Comment: This document you linked refers to launching a projectile from some height $h$ and some initial speed $v$ and angle $\theta$. However, it treats $v$ and $h$ as completely independent. If you scroll to the end, it mentions that for a height of $1.5h$ and angle $26.6^\circ$ the range will be doubled. In the problem OP asked, there is a ‘trade off’ — (Assuming constant angle) if the height is smaller, speed is larger, but then the time the projectile has in the air is shorter. You must account for that, and the different possibilities for the launch angle.

Comment: You are correct that the document treats h and v independent -- but the problem links them together via v = sqrt(2 * H' * g).  That is, we can compute R as a function of H'.